# Minecraft Bedrock minecart train

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I ran into some hastle myself trying to do this today:

I've been planning on creating an amusement park on minecraft bedrock. For this there of course needs to be rollercoasters. Is there a way to link minecarts using commandblocks and ensure that the minecart will face the correct way and will always stay on the rails? This is what I got now:

`execute @e[name=CT1, type=minecart] ^ ^ ^ tp @e[name=CT2, type=minecart] ^-1.6 ^ ^` 
However this makes the minecart teleport like crazy and forces it off the rail. Is there a way to make this better? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to teleport the minecarts to specific places on some powered rail at the start, and then start them all off at the same time? Then you also wouldn't have to  worry about the 100-block limit for executing your repeat command.

Comment: @DM01131 wdym "100 block limit"

Comment: @Penguin Command blocks can only execute commands over a distance of 100 blocks. This might be an obstacle to using @user15270366's original command, ``execute @e[name=CT1, type=minecart] ^ ^ ^ tp @e[name=CT2, type=minecart] ^-1.6 ^ ^``, depending on how large their ride is. I believe functions are able to bypass this limit, but they might not be the simplest solution for what @user15270366 wants to do.

Comment: @DM01131 that's... not true. Im not quite sure where you heard that but I can assue you ive used command blocks over distances of hundreds upon hundreds of blocks away

Comment: @Penguin are you sure? I am certain I have experienced this in my world. Are you saying for example things like ``/setblock`` can work when they are executed at say ``1000,100,1000`` and the block is at say ``0,0,0``, as long as the chunk is loaded? Also, just to confirm we're both talking about BE?

Comment: @DM01131 yes and yes. I do believe the setblock command in specific will work even if the target chunk isnt loaded as long as it has been generated (not 100% sure on that). But I am 100% sure that there is no 100 block limit as Ive used these types of things many times